# Proof Explanation - Rudin's RCA Theorem 2.13

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

Please help me with the following two questions (proof attached below):

1. They define $h_i = (1-g_1)(1-g_2)\ldots (1-g_{i-1})g_i$. Why is $h_i \prec V_i$? Here's my thoughts: Since $g_i \prec V_i$ for all $1\le i\le n$ - $V_i$ is open, $g_i\in C_c(X)$, $0\le g_i\le 1$ and $\text{supp}(g_i)\subset V_i$ for all $1\le i\le n$. Then, $0\le g_i\le 1 \implies 0\le 1-g_i\le 1$. Clearly, $0 \le h_i \le 1$ for all $1\le i\le n$. The support of $h_i$ will be $\text{supp}(h_i) = \text{supp} (g_1)\cap \text{supp}(g_2) \cap \ldots\cap \text{supp}(g_i)$, right? If yes, then $\text{supp}(h_i) \in V_i$ and we are done.
2. Why is $K\subset H_1 \cup H_2\cup \ldots\cup H_n$? I was able to show the rest.

> [image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: For Q2, if $x\in K$ then $x\in W_{x_j}$ for some $ j\le m. $  And $W_{x_j}\subset \overline W_{x_j}\subset V_i$ for some $i\le n. $ So for some $ j\le m$ and some $i\le n$ we have $x\in W_{x_j}\subset \overline W_{x_j}\subset H_i$.... I dislike the author's use of "lie in" in the 1st paragraph of the proof. I would replace it with "are subsets of".

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now! How about Q1, is my reasoning correct? @DanielWainfleet

Comment: Yes. But more simply, if $x\in X\setminus V_i$ then $0\le h_i(x)\le g_i(x)=0$ because $g_i\prec V_i$.... BTW you have a typo in the 1st line of 1. The subscript $n$'s should be $i$'s.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fixed the typo as well. @DanielWainfleet